# FastLane Screengrab for androids

Tags: android-studio, fastlane, screen-grab

I'm trying to integrate fastlane screengrab into the android application and i'm running into the following issue when i execute the command. screengrab.

```
[16:30:42]: ▸ INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: id=ActivityManagerService
[16:30:42]: ▸ INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: Error=Unable to find instrumentation info for: ComponentInfo{com.example.android.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner}
[16:30:42]: ▸ INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: -1
[16:30:42]: ▸ android.util.AndroidException: INSTRUMENTATION_FAILED: com.example.android.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
```

Comment: i have no idea why it's picking ...test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit path when i specify only
{com.example.android/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner

Comment: Hi Andrei, I'd need more information to help you get something working. Can you provide more information about how you are invoking screengrab? I would need to know about the command line call or action invocation from your Fastfile. Also, any relevant configuration from your project: show your Screengrabfile, if you use it, and build.gradle definitions of your applicationId and testInstrumentationRunner. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just add testInstrumentationRunner into the build.gradle file

```
android {
        ...
        defaultConfig {
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
    }
```

And run the command:

> fastlane screengrab